# Does mysql use BFS or DFS?

Tags: mysql, database, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Does Mysql store the data in a data graph structure? Let's say I: `insert into table (name) values ("Peter")`. Is Peter stored in a graph? 
If that's the case and I do: `select from table where name="peter"` how is Peter found? Does it use **breadth first search** or ***depth first search***?

The thing is that I'm studying BFS and DFS but...I was wondering what the point in learning it was if it is far easier saving data to a database and just accessing data.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

If the `name` column is indexed, MySQL stores the values in a B+tree. Looking up the name "peter" does not need to use BFS or DFS. It can search in `O(log n)` time by traversing the branch of the tree directly to the value "peter".

If the `name` column is not indexed, MySQL does a table-scan, searching every row of the table, and comparing the `name` attribute to the value "peter". Attributes are stored in the clustered index, which is also a B+tree.

A B+tree is different from a B-tree in that the leaf nodes have a pointer to the next leaf node. So MySQL does a table-scan by finding the first leaf node, and then searching in `O(n)` time, visiting only other leaf nodes. It does not need to do BFS or DFS to visit every leaf node.

Comment: I think this answer slightly misses the point and the spirit of the question. Sure, when we speak of breadth- or depth-first search it's often used to describe full tree traversal. With InnoDB's methodologies, nodes (leafs or pointers) aren't traversed per se, but they (and their "pages") are *written to* in a way that models BFS or DFS. In other words, in one of these orders. Which order still remains an outstanding question from my point of view. For me at least, the spirit of the question is this: Is MySQL's implementation of B(-/+)Tree indexes optimized for disk I/O or memory? BSF or DFS?

Comment: I'll add that it needn't be one or the other, but it can't be neither. There are other "hybrid" algorithms that split the tree up and traverse in various ways. (eg. Eytzinger or Van Emde Boas.) They all result in a "list" of sorts, and are written to disk in a specific (linear) sequence. I'm still trying to understand what that is, and why. Again, assuming it's for read performance from disk, probably something like BFS based on my research, but still looking for something definitive (and digestible!) for InnoDB.